# Insert string after 4 results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using the following code to get results from a SQL Server:

```
string content = "Test value"    

try {
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand    myCommand = new SqlCommand("select name from Persons", 
                                             myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- " + myReader["name"].ToString());

    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
}
```

What I want is to insert the value of the string "Content" inside the while loop after 4 results, e.g:

- Name 1 #
- Name 2 #
- Name 3 #
- Name 4 #
- Test value
- Name 5 #

Comment: This code would benefit from Code Review Stack Exchange. Give it a try.

Comment: If the code is not working as intended (the description sounds like it does not do what OP wants), then the code is not suitable for Code Review. Posting not working or asking to add features is off-topic on Code Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an index variable:

```
var index = 0;
while(myReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("- " + myReader["name"].ToString());
    if (++index == 4) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test value");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string content = "Test value"

            try
            {
                var counter = 1;
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select name from Persons",
                    myConnection);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    if (counter == 4)
                    {
                        counter = 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(content);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("- " + myReader["name"].ToString());

                    counter++;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
int index = 0;
while (myReader.Read()) {
    if ((index != 4)) {
        index++;
    }
    else {
        // Intert your Code for the Content String Here
    }
}
```